# Controversial question getting worse

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

**Mod's notice:** *Given the clear outcome of the poll below, I've now closed the question (MO).*

I have the highest voted answer to [this controversial post regarding racism against an Indian student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155185/how-to-proceed-after-being-threatened-and-treated-poorly-by-university-faculty-a/155158#155158).  The claims in the OP are quite extraordinary, but the poster deserves the benefit of the doubt, so I gave sincere advice.  Then I read this reply by the OP on [my answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/155158/57314) that was just posted yesterday (September 19th):

> In the end, I remarked to this individual that one serious problem is that I'm a high caste individual, and look at white people in my university as an abominable low caste, and that automatically creates a lot of problems.

I had to re-read it to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding.  Then I looked back over the rest of the posts, and I'm not sure what to make of it.  The OP implicates the following list of people with some very over-the-top racism, including physical confrontations and swearing:

- Other PhD students
- The department chair
- The Dean
- HR
- Multiple faculty

It's certainly *possible* that this person landed at the most racist institution in all of Massachusetts.  But in light of the quote above, it seems more plausible that either the OP is the problem, or more likely, the whole post is an elaborate and puzzling attempt at trolling.

At a minimum the conversation has become so focused on this person's bizarre situation that I can't imagine it being particularly useful to other readers.  I'm not sure what the appropriate action would be though.

So what does the rest of the community think?  Am I being overly harsh in my judgment after reading the above comment?

Some more context from the linked chat room from the same OP:

> I wrote this after documenting a huge number of incidents inside our
> department, and got a reply from the Title IX office saying there's
> nothing really wrong. Actually I'm not sure if all of the documented
> incidents could be dealt with by the Title IX office, but certainly
> there were major serious incidents there that they should have dealt
> with. Caste is officially a protected category in this university. I
> felt a bit sick myself talking in this manner with these disgusting
> hypocrites who pretend to be such progressives that they make caste a
> protected class, but with this cabal, it felt fine.    I wanted to see
> their reaction; if they would do anything now that I claimed that the
> whole problem was basically casteist. This was meant to slander them
> even further. I mean, caste should be a protected class, but very very
> few places in the US have added caste as a protected class, if I'm not
> wrong. I was basically baiting them at this point. I hope I could make
> the context clearer; I was basically trolling, and trying to conjure
> up an image of myself as a casteist a**hole and that too by calling
> white Americans in my university lower castes by default, in a
> farcical tone. None of this is really relevant here, but from my high
> school and college days (my opinion changed from middle school when I
> was more swayed by the opinion of General category folk around me), I
> have openly advocated for caste based reservation in India and why it
> is important for it to continue for at least a few generations, and
> have faced the wrath of some of my friends for saying this. Of the
> handful of really close friends I made in college, about half of them
> were from a non privileged caste. We never discussed caste then of
> course. In fact literally four of my most closest friends who I hung out with
> in college were all from a non privileged caste. I've lost touch a
> little bit, but good old days, and we'll meet again! But again, this
> is what you would call "reactive behavior" at best, but I felt the
> time for continuing politeness with our university administration was
> pretty much over, after their continuing dismissals of all incidents.

Further [comments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155185/how-to-proceed-after-being-threatened-and-treated-poorly-by-university-faculty-a#comment416031_155186):

> This was exactly what I had written in the very last email to the
> Title IX office: "Actually a lot of these problems stem from the fact
> that I'm a high caste individual, and look around in this university
> and see a dimwitted peasant class that is a natural anathema for me.
> Do you think that can enable you to take some kind of action?" I did
> not say 'white people in the university were an abominable lower
> caste'. The idea was to bark back. The context was that this
> university made headlines by adding caste as a protected class, and
> thus showed off it's progressive cred.I should mention that in the
> prior emails, the documentation that I had was huge, and this thread
> or the chat probably covers at most 30% of everything documented
> there.

OP later clarified:

> I hope in the discussion, I could make it clear that I don't actually view white people in my university as a lower caste, or want to look down on lower castes in India.

Comment: I noticed exactly the same comment as you. FWIW, I certainly think the OP is not trolling and is sincere in their beliefs; you probably have enough rep to see some of their deleted posts from March 2020, such as https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145334/harassment-while-doing-phd-in-mathematics-part-3  (which I can't, although I had bookmarked it at the time)

Comment: Of course, whether their beliefs are **accurate** is something I cannot possibly judge with any, erm, accuracy. I do agree with your assessment that "At a minimum the conversation has become so focused on this person's bizarre situation that I can't imagine it being particularly useful to other readers"

Comment: I added some more info from the OP from the chat room. Gonna be honest, we should probably just nuke it from orbit

Comment: I momentarily locked that question while we sort things out.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I feel too junior in this community to make recommendations but that would be my preferred outcome FWIW. (I assume that's an Aliens reference?)

Comment: There is also enough information on the post now to easily identify the university in question, if not the individual themself or the faculty involved.

Comment: I concur with your concerns. I'm inclined to say we should post possible paths forward as answers to this question, and let the community decide how to proceed by voting. What do you think?

Comment: The user has previously posted under a specific name, easily tied to content in the questions asked and to a real human. Either the user is that person and is quite disturbed or trolling (and if the latter, then by using their own name also the former), or is someone else and is purely smearing this person+trolling. I don't think they can be helped here if they are legitimate.

Comment: Can any mod tell me why [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/155153/546) was marked R/A and deleted?

Comment: @scaaahu "Lunatic" is inappropriate.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Thanks. I missed it.

Comment: To the mods, I think the penalty is too harsh (regarding my previous comment). we could replace "It may be that you are a lunatic" by a milder one, like "It may be that you have a problem". The whole answer is not that bad.

Comment: @scaaahu The question was first flagged by a user and the flag was first reviewed by me. I agreed with the flag because, in addition to "it may be that you are a lunatic" I find it also problematic the sentence "Your account is one sided and doesn't make me think that you're the victim". I'll flag that answer so that another moderator can review the decision.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I didn't notice that answer in the first place (I thought it was marked R/A for reasons). Then I read the meta here, "I'm a high caste individual, and look at white people in my university as an abominable low caste", I kind of think may be "_Your account is one sided and doesn't make me think that you're the victim._" is right. Thus, my two previous comments. But, anyway, you mods decide. Maybe it's too late

Comment: Just a correction: I had mentioned the former departmental chair, not the current departmental chair, who is universally well respected. Also, in my post from March, I had mentioned incidents with a faculty member in a nearby university, which were also very disturbing, and about which I had spoken with an Emeritus faculty member in our department (and an eminent combinatorialist and former Putnam Fellow), and he had agreed that I was getting abused in that situation.

Comment: Also, if it is of any value, I want to assure that the post was not an elaborate attempt at trolling; and if you ask some Chinese students in our department they will also tell you about the behavior of our teaching faculty member unless they fear repurcussions, and literally everyone in the department knows about this specific grad student I'm speaking of; although I don't think he has said such extended amount of crap as he has to me in such an offensive tone, being in the same year as me for one thing.

Comment: I think this over the top racism has one important reason, which I will not opine on here, since that will give away the institution.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano As that's my answer I don't feel that the penalty is too harsh (I should have chosen different language). If you'd like to edit it down and reopen it you are welcome to do so.

Comment: I finally went and reread the entire thing, and I don't think it's a likely outcome but this entire thing raises a bunch of red flags for workplace violence. He clearly views his coworkers as lesser humans, he believes that they're all out to get him, and he's been involved in some sort of physical altercation with at least one of his coworkers. This is borderline and I don't know which way I'd vote on it, but one option should probably be to notify his campus security.

Comment: I took a look at the deleted answer on which Massimo requested a second opinion. I think the deletion was reasonable, and while there might have been a way to salvage it with aggressive editing, I recommend that we just leave it be, particularly since the entire post seems destined for closure (and probably deletion) in any case.

Comment: @laputalanglang - yes, please see the appropriate [uses of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and our [code of conduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct). Your comments that accuse our users of racism (without evidence) and post unrelated material ("spam") violate both of these, and may therefore be deleted without warning. Please be aware that we have extended you the benefit of the doubt in that we have so far only deleted the inappropriate comments; however, users who continually or seriously violate our code of conduct may be suspended.

Comment: I'm sure you are an educated person, and have critical thinking skills; do you understand how CJRD's comments above are unsafe?

Comment: I have chosen not to involve myself in that discussion at this time; however, I see no issues that require immediate moderator attention.

Answer (score 26):

*Upvote this answer if you agree we should close (for any reason); downvote if you strongly disagree.*

**Close the question.** This "depends on individual factors": if all these details are really needed to understand the question, the question does not belong on this site.

Answer (score 7):

*Upvote this answer if you agree we should delete (for any reason); downvote if you strongly disagree.*

**Delete the question** (in addition to closing). The situation seems enough of a mess that suggestions based on an incomplete understanding of it can easily do harm.

Comment: I wonder why you have a "new contributor" flag when you have 18.8k rep and have been a user for 6 years

Comment: @Azor - Looks like their first answer on meta!

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim - indeed, it is a weird quirk of the Metas and how 'new' is tracked...

Answer (score -6):

Victim-blaming is often a manifestation of prejudice.  It's a manifestation of prejudice that is seen from time to time on this site.  We are not defense attorneys, so there is no need for us to investigate the victim.

Comment: Does this imply that we should leave the question open? Or only that we should be cognizant of this whatever we do?

Comment: Be cognizant.  This response is neutral on the open/close" issue.

Comment: I view this a bit differently. It's not that we are defense attorneys investigating a victim, but I do think we act as self-scouts.

Comment: @BryanKrause No idea what that means.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist A self-scout (kind of borrowing a sports term here) is responsible for looking at your own weaknesses, finding holes in your defense or weaknesses in your offense. I don't think questioning someone's presentation is blaming the victim when the purpose is to say "here's how your approach paints you in a bad light". "Investigating the victim" is not a bad thing when it's done from the victim's point of view, to strengthen their position, rather than to truly dismantle it.

Answer (score -7):

*Upvote this answer if you agree we should heavily edit the question and leave open (for any reason); downvote if you strongly disagree.*

**Heavily edit the question, then leave open.** We can edit to (1) generalize the question, and (2) remove some of the troubling comments cited above. This will allow us to keep the existing answers intact.

Answer (score -15):

*Upvote this answer if you agree we should leave open in its present state (for any reason); downvote if you strongly disagree.*

**Leave the question open in its present state**.